# Converting a bytes array to stream

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is there a way to convert bytes array returned from sql server to a stream object in c# ?
I want to be able to do something like this below

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\sample\sample\sample.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
//bytes array will be saved in the database
//The following will be returned from the database and i need it to be in a stream
Stream s = (Stream)bytes;
```

Is there any other way of saving it in sql server other than in a varbinary(MAX) format?

Answer (score 9):

it's easy. Just use `MemoryStream` to convert this.

```
Stream S = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

or this.

```
    static void Write(Stream s, Byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(s))
        {
            writer.Write(bytes);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MemoryStream` class to convert a byte array to a `Stream` Object

```
Stream st = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```